# SVN commit inside a bash script not working correctly

Tags: svn, bash, commit

I have a small example script, part of a bigger script, which is working fine except for the svn commit part.

```
root@dx-svn02:~# cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
CMD="svn update /mnt/checkout/dx-test/"
echo "INFO>>>: $CMD"
$CMD

CMD="svn commit -m 'Updated various bits' /mnt/checkout/dx-test/"
echo "$CMD"
$CMD
root@dx-svn02:~# ./test.sh 
INFO>>>: svn update /mnt/checkout/dx-test/
At revision 3.
svn commit -m 'Updated various bits' /mnt/checkout/dx-test/
svn: '/' is not a working copy
root@dx-svn02:~# svn commit -m 'Updated various bits' /mnt/checkout/dx-test/
root@dx-svn02:~#
```

I really don't understand how the update can work but the commit doesn't.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what's the root of your version-controlled code (i.e. highest-level dir with a `.svn` sub-dir)?

Comment: does it work if you cd to `dx-test` and do a commit from there? I think the `is not a working copy` error is complaining that `/` is not part of the svn repo.

Comment: ButI'm not trying to commit /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single-quoted string doesn't remain quoted when you interpolate it.

In other words, you would like to have

```
ARGV[0] = svn
ARGV[1] = commit
ARGV[2] = -m
ARGV[3] = Updated various bits
...
```

... but the way the quoting works out, you are getting

```
ARGV[0] = svn
ARGV[1] = commit
ARGV[2] = -m
ARGV[3] = 'Updated
ARGV[4] = various
...
```

You're probably better off using something like `set -x` to see the commands as you execute them.

Comment: Yeh that sounds right, 
I'm trying 

CMD="svn commit -m \"Updated various bits\" /mnt/checkout/dx-test/" 

instead but now I'm getting 

./test.sh: line 5: svn commit -m "Updated various bits" /mnt/checkout/dx-test/: No such file or directory

Comment: Repeat, you're probably better off not putting your commands in a variable before attempting to execute them.  If you need to see what gets executed, add `set -x` to the start of your script.

Comment: Yeh I switched it to just do this instead
`#!/bin/bash
echo "CMD<<< "
set -x
svn commit -m "Updated various bits" /mnt/checkout/dx-test/
set +x`

Thanks a lot